# Python not recognizing all elements of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a molar mass calculator using python 2.7. My current program works by asking for user input of a chemical formula, such as "C 6 H 12 O 6."
Then, the program turns the input into a list, and then separates the numbers from the characters. To do that, the user list is compared to the element list.
If a character matches up with an element, the program appends that element to a separate list. However, for some reason, 24 (originally 49) elements are not recognized as being in the list of elements, and therefore are not appended onto the new list.
For example, the program doesn't append "Mg" or "Al" to the new list. I have decreased the list of unrecognized elements from 49 to 24 by converting my lists and the input to uppercase with upper().
However, the 24 elements still do not get recognized. Below is the code that I believe is the problem.

```
reflistchar = ['H', 'He', 'Li', 'Be', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'O', 'F', 'Ne','Na', 'Mg'] 
#A separate loop converts each element to uppercase. Shortened for simplicity.

s1 = raw_input('Formula: ')
s = s1.upper()
slist = s.split(' ')

x = len(slist)
y = 0
for i in range(x):
if any(i in reflistchar for i in slist[y]):
  slchar.append(slist[y])
y += 1
```

For example:

Input:

```
element1 element2 element3 element4 element5
```

Expected Output:

```
[element1, element2, element3, element4, element5]
```

Current Output:

```
[element2, element3, element5]
```

As I tried to show above, the user inputs 5 elements but only some of them are added to the list. The elements that are not added are consistently not added no matter what order they are inputted in.
I think this may be because these elements denote some sort of python function or variable. I greatly appreciate any advice on how to get the program to recognize them.

Comment: Your `any` is checking if any of the *individual characters* of `slist[y]` are in `reflistchar`, not if the actual list element is in `reflistchar`.

Comment: Also, you've kind of missed the point of a `for` loop, with the separate `y` counter and the unused `i`.

Comment: You're also converting the input to upper case, while your list contains mixed case elements.

Comment: @mpf82 OP also convert the list to uppercase, at least that's what I understood from his commented code. What is `slchar`?

Comment: ah, my bad, I did skip the comment

Comment: Thank you @user2357112 . How would I make it so that it checks for the actual list elements? Also, I admit I don't know as much as I should about `for` loops.

Comment: @mpf82 `slchar` is a separate list from the program where all the characters are appended. I didn't think it was necessary to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of pointers...

First, `s.split()` would be a better alternative to `s.split(' ')` since it handles multiple spaces better.

Next, you are iterating over a loop,... but not using `i` anywhere. That's not the main problem though.

Thirdly, the main problem, is this:

```
any(i in reflistchar for i in slist[y])
```

`slist[y]` is a *string*. For example, if `slist[y]` holds `'Al'`, then you first check for `'A'` in `reflistchar`, and then check for `'l'` in `reflistchar`... Because you can iterate over strings too! This is why you're not getting what you want. You should instead use the `in` operator to check for existence.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
reflistchar = ['H', 'He', 'Li', 'Be', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'O', 'F', 'Ne','Na', 'Mg'] 
string_list = raw_input('Formula: ').upper().split()

reflistchar = set(reflistchar)

elements = []
for e in string_list:
    if e in reflistchar:
        elements.append(e)
```

*Bonus!* I converted `reflistchar` to a `set` for fast, constant `O(1)` lookup.